# What comprehensive grammar books are available?

Tags: grammar, resources, simplified-characters, books, academic

I have found many grammar books, but none that go beyond the low-intermediate level. Some textbook series contain lots of grammar, but this is spread out across many books and difficult to quickly cross-reference. Are there any books or volumes of books containing all Chinese grammar or all sentence patterns, similar in scope to Diane Larsen-Freeman's *The Grammar Book*?

Comment: This question was more or less fine at the beginning, but now I'm forced to close it. We need to raise the quality of the site and for this reason, we need to avoid list questions. There is a specific CW question created to group resources, make sure you read the main post.

Answer (score 2):

[Chinese: A Comprehensive Grammar (Comprehensive Grammars)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Chinese-Comprehensive-Grammar-Grammars/dp/0415150329/sr=1-3/qid=1164505918/ref=sr_1_3/203-5787852-6539128?ie=UTF8&s=books)

Comment: Does this book describe everything about the structure of modern Chinese?

Answer (score 1):

AllSet Learning just launched a grammar web site, and the front page has [a list of reference books](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/#Referenced_Throughout) that they used to prepare it. The site itself also looks useful. There's not a lot of detail yet, but they say they will continue working to add more content.

Answer (score 0):

Yuen Ren Chao: A Grammar of Spoken Chinese. University of California Press, Berkeley, 1968, ISBN 0-520-00219-9.

Answer (score 0):

*A Practical Chinese Grammar for Foreigners*, which is a great book for non-Chinese speakers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Nancy. Are there any specific features of the book that make it particularly useful?